# MySQL order by column, equal spread of values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am looking to select a subset of data from a table but would like to ensure I get an equal mix of different 'types' from a column.

For example, if the table had a column called 'animal' that was populated with the following:

```
name, animal
'Bob', 'cat'
'Fred','cat'
'Jim','dog'
'Sam','dog'
'Andy','snake'
'Paul','snake'
```

I would like to select the rows in an order that has an even mix of animal types, so the result would be:

```
['Bob','cat'],
['Jim','dog'],
['Andy','snake'],
['Fred','cat'],
['Sam','dog'],
['Paul','snake']
```

Similar to randomising, but ensuring that all types are included equally. Is there a way to do this in mysql?

Comment: Do you mean the same number of each type of animal (in this case, 2 of each)? Or are you saying you want them rearranged into sets (cat, dog, snake, {repeat})? Because other than re-ordering the rows, these two sets of results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives every name in the table an index with reference to the animal they own and then selects each index-animal in turn:

```
SELECT name, animal
  FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
             WHEN @animal = animal THEN @row := @row + 1
             ELSE @row := 0
           END row_num,
           name, 
           @animal := animal animal
      FROM owner
      JOIN (SELECT @animal := null, @row := 0) init
  ORDER BY animal, name
        ) temp
 ORDER BY row_num, animal
```

[See Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6f517/1)

Note any spare animals will be appended to the end.. is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks Arth, this is perfect.